# Passing variable 'chart' from controller to view

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to create charts on my application. I have the following error when I am trying to pass a variable to a view:

> Undefined variable: chart (View:
>   /Users/ZK/Desktop/project/resources/views/home.blade.php)

I have pasted my controller code below;

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use Charts;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $chart = Charts::new('link', 'highcharts')
            ->setTitle("My Chart")
            ->setLabels("A", "B", "C")
            ->setValues([100, 50, 25])
            ->setElementLabel(["Total Users"]);

        return view('home', [ 'chart' => $chart ]);

    }
```

home.blade.php code;

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Dashboard</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    {!! $chart->render() !!}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Within my layouts.app I have also added the assets for my chart in the header;

```
 {!! Charts::assets() !!}
```

Can anyone suggest what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: this is weird , your code looks ok for me,  if you remove  Charts::assets() , does it work ? Are you sure you are using that controller method to view , maybe paste whole debug trade in here

Comment: Are you calling the right action, i.e. presumably `/dashboard` and not just the home URL which happens to render the same view? If so, could you add your routing config for that specific controller to the question?

Comment: Thank you both for your reply, I was not calling the correct controller in my routes. I'm new to laravel so just getting to grips. Silly mistake! Appreciate your help